# Breaking changes in Rails 4 JSON rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I started a new app atop Rails 4 and I've noticed what seems to be a breaking change in how JSON rendering is implemented by default, but I can't find it written up anywhere so I was wondering if anyone can give me some insight on (1) whether the API has actually changed and (2) how I can obtain the behavior that I need (namely, the old behavior).

In particular, what I'm seeing is that, where in Rails 3

```
@answer.as_json
```

...would return...

```
{
  id: 1,
  body: "lorem ipsum..."
  ....
}
```

in Rails 4 it seems that the same method is returning:

```
{
  'answer':
    {
      id: 1,
      body: "lorem ipsum..."
      ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone else confirm that this behavior has changed? Is there any way to get the old behavior back short of overriding as_json for every model?

This new implementation is making it more cumbersome to return JSON responses containing multiple models (which now would either have to be done with a hash merge in the "render :json ..." call in the controller action or by overriding as_json).

Comment: did you look in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json` that controls the top-level behaviour of `as_json` method. The name is self-explanatory, I guess.

As for a breaking API change: If you dig into the source, you can see that the default value for this option was changed to `true` in Rails [4.0.0.beta1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.beta1/activerecord/lib/active_record/serialization.rb#L8) but later it was reverted to `false` in Rails [4.0.0.rc1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.rc1/activerecord/lib/active_record/serialization.rb#L8).

If you want to be sure that JSON will not contain root node, specify `include_root_in_json` option in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish this had been better publicized. At the very least, when people on beta1 (or any future version that changes the default) notice this hopefully they'll land on this page.